# online DMS document editing in non MS environments

Tags: linux, alfresco, openoffice.org, dms

I am looking at possible DMS solutions and have a basic question:

Our requirement is that users must be able to edit documents "on-line"

e.g. not have to save a doc to their local PC and then re-upload the docs.
(Users should be able to edit the doc and push save, and it happens to the on-line doc.)

We prefer a non-Microsoft solution (most of our users are on Linux), and it must be able to be hosted internally (on an Intranet) -  prefer LibreOffice or something similar that works on multiple OSes

I have tried the demo of openkm and it seems to make you download a doc first, and manually upload it again, as there is no edit button.  Did not see an alfresco on-line demo, so I could not try it there.

Can anyone suggest a system that allows such in place editing of spreadsheets and documents

One suggestion/comment I received is that in place editing may only be possible using IE / work with OLE.  As most of our users are using non-IE browsers, that is not an option for us.

Comment: Please check this: http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/edit-online-libreoffice-openoffice

Comment: You can also leverage Alfresco's GoogleDocs integration - you can try it in Alfresco Cloud: my.alfresco.com - it will be merge into the Community/Enterprise branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up the previous comments:
You can either use:

- http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/edit-online-libreoffice-openoffice - An Alfresco addon to online edit documents using LibreOffice via WebDav
- Use the LibreOffice 4.x CMIS integration: http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2012/11/01/cmis-support-in-libreoffice-experimental-features/
- or use Alfresco's Google Docs integration (v2 should be in current 4.2 nightly builts)

Comment: Or wait a little bit and use OpenOffice with the [CMIS UCP binding](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Summer_of_Code_2013/CMIS_UCP) that's being worked on by a GSOC student

Comment: We are trialling CMIS with LibreOffice 4.x now, and this seems at first glance to be the way to go.